# PINTERFACE_REFERENCE and MinGW W64

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, mingw, wdk

I'm trying to compile my working 32-Bit DLL project which communicates with USB-Devices to a 64-Bit Windows-DLL.

The sources compile fine with MinGW32 but if I try to build them with MinGW W64 I get an error within hidclass.h:

hidclass.h|132|error: unknown type name ‘PINTERFACE_REFERENCE’

I can't find anything about PINTERFACE_REFERENCE so I'd be glad for every hint about this.

Building it in 32-Bit is not an option because it will be used within Java via JNI and I have to support both 32- and 64-Bit JVMs.

I know that I could do minor changes to my code and switch to Microsofts Visual C++ compiler using VisualDDK and the Windows Driver Kit but I'd love to continue using my free toolchain since it works flawless for 32-Bit builds and I don't have to think about licensing issues.

Comment: MinGW tends to peter out when the declarations get obscure (like most of the WDM) or are hard to reverse-engineer from public documentation.  I could easily give you the declaration but that comes from a tainted source, it doesn't help you do what you need to do.  Which is reverse-engineering it yourself and submitting a patch to the project.

Comment: Thanks. Since time is an issue for this project I'm using the Microsoft toolchain now.